# How to check for modifications on local svn checkout with C#?

Tags: c#, svn

I want to find out if there are any modifications/uncommited changes in a local svn-checkout folder (without opening any dialog).

I used to use the svn-command-line commands but I did not find a way to do it there.

Edit:

To cleariefy: I want to create a C#-function without user interaction which looks like this:

bool CheckForModifications(string svnCheckoutPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Victor Mikó's Answer I was able to use the SharpSvn-library (installed with nuGet). I created the following function to check if a given folder has svn-modifications:

```
public static bool? HasFolderSvnModifications(string localPath)
{
    using (var client = new SvnClient())
    {
        // Check if there are any modifications in the checkout
        Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
        if (client.GetStatus(localPath, out statuses))
        {
            foreach (var item in statuses)
            {
                if (item.Modified)
                {
                    
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is how I use the function:

```
var hasModifications = HasFolderSvnModifications(localPath);
if (hasModifications.HasValue)
{
    if (hasModifications.Value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is at least one modified item in " + localPath);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no modifications in " + localPath);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Problem with queryind for svn-modifications in " + localPath);
}
```

Comment: Nice - happy you figure it out!!